# Reflection Mapping in OpenGL ES

Tags: reflection, opengl-es, shader

I am trying to implement the reflection mapping in OpenGL ES 2.0 for 'sphere'.
I have done the skybox.
For sphere rendering, the reflection shaders i have used are:

Environment mapping (Sphere) vertex shader::

```
precision highp float;
uniform mat4    u_mvMatrix; // ModelView Matrix
uniform mat4    u_mvpMatrix; // ModelViewProjection Matrix

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_envmapNormal;

varying vec3 v_eyecoordEyeReflection;

vec3 v_eyecoordPosition;
vec3 v_eyecoordNormal;

void main()
 {
    // position and normal in model coordinates
    vec4 modelCoordPosition = a_position;
    vec3 modelCoordNormal   = a_envmapNormal;

    // Calculate position in eye space
    v_eyecoordPosition = vec3(u_mvMatrix * modelCoordPosition);

    // Calculate and normalize eye space normal
    vec3 eyecoordNormal    = vec3(u_mvMatrix * vec4(modelCoordNormal, 0.0));
    v_eyecoordNormal        = normalize(eyecoordNormal);
    // Calculate reflection vector
    v_eyecoordEyeReflection = reflect(v_eyecoordPosition, v_eyecoordNormal);

    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;
}
```

Environment mapping (Sphere) Fragment shader

```
precision highp float;
uniform lowp samplerCube baseCubeMapTexture;
varying vec3 v_eyecoordEyeReflection;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor  = textureCube(baseCubeMapTexture, v_eyecoordEyeReflection);
}
```

But i am not getting correct output.
When the sphere is rotated, the texture is not changing.

what is the error in the shader?

---

---

Thanks Andon...
I used your shader code.
But i am getting white sphere.

Sphere Normals are calculated using:

```
    #define ANGLE_STEP      ((2.0f * OGLES_PI) / ((float) NUM_OF_SLICES))
    for ( iCnti = 0; iCnti < NUM_OF_PARALLELS + 1; iCnti++ )    {
        for ( iCntj = 0; iCntj < NUM_OF_SLICES + 1; iCntj++ )   {
            pSphereNormals[iNormalIndex + 0] = sin(ANGLE_STEP * (FLOAT) iCnti )* sin (ANGLE_STEP *(FLOAT)iCntj);
            pSphereNormals[iNormalIndex + 1] = cos(ANGLE_STEP * (FLOAT) iCnti );
            pSphereNormals[iNormalIndex + 2] = sin(ANGLE_STEP * (FLOAT) iCnti )* cos (ANGLE_STEP *(FLOAT)iCntj);
            iNormalIndex += 3;
        }
    }
```

My View Matrix "matViewMatrix" is derived from (http://www.learnopengles.com/tag/linmath-h/ mat4x4_look_at())
MyCameraLookAt(matViewMatrix, 0.0f , 0.0f, -2.0f,  0.0f , 0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f , 1.0f, 0.0f);

The Inverse matrix   InvViewMat is  // inverse() function is taken from http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebCore/WebCore-514/platform/graphics/transforms/TransformationMatrix.cpp

```
    InvViewMat[0][0] = -1.000000   InvViewMat[1][0] = -0.000000   InvViewMat[2][0] = 0.000000    InvViewMat[3][0] = -0.000000
    InvViewMat[0][1] = -0.000000   InvViewMat[1][1] = 1.000000    InvViewMat[2][1] = -0.000000   InvViewMat[3][1] = -0.000000
    InvViewMat[0][2] =  0.000000   InvViewMat[1][2] = -0.000000   InvViewMat[2][2] = -1.000000   InvViewMat[3][2] = -2.000000
    InvViewMat[0][3] = -0.000000   InvViewMat[1][3] = 0.000000    InvViewMat[2][3] = 0.000000    InvViewMat[3][3] = 1.000000
```

Is there any problem with my matrix values or any of my calculations?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a sphere centered at the camera's origin (eye-space), then no matter how you rotate it the position and normals in eye-space are always going to be the same at any location on screen. That is the definition of a sphere - every vertex is the same distance (radius) from the center.

You actually need to do this in ***world-space*** (that position will vary as you rotate the sphere).

Now, this brings up an issue - you only have a `ModelView` matrix (which transforms from object-space to eye-space). You are going to need to split your Model and View matrices to do this and for convenience you should pass the inverse of the View matrix to GLSL.

#### Below is a modified Vertex Shader that does what you want:

```c
precision highp float;
uniform mat4    u_vInvMatrix; // Inverse View Matrix -- NEW
uniform mat4    u_mvMatrix;   // ModelView Matrix
uniform mat4    u_mvpMatrix;  // ModelViewProjection Matrix

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec3 a_envmapNormal;

//varying vec3 v_eyecoordEyeReflection; // YOU DO NOT WANT EYE-SPACE
varying vec3 v_worldReflection;         // Use world-space instead -- MODIFIED

vec3 v_eyecoordPosition;
vec3 v_eyecoordNormal;

void main()
 {
    // position and normal in model coordinates
    vec4 modelCoordPosition = a_position;
    vec3 modelCoordNormal   = a_envmapNormal;

    // Calculate position in eye space
    v_eyecoordPosition   = vec3(u_mvMatrix * modelCoordPosition);

    // Calculate and normalize eye space normal
    vec3 eyecoordNormal  = vec3(u_mvMatrix * vec4(modelCoordNormal, 0.0));
    v_eyecoordNormal     = normalize(eyecoordNormal);

    // Calculate reflection vector (eye-space)
    vec3 eyeReflection   = reflect(v_eyecoordPosition, v_eyecoordNormal);

    // Transform the reflection into world-space -- NEW
    v_worldReflection    = vec3 (u_vInvMatrix * vec4 (eyeReflection, 0.0f));

    gl_Position = u_mvpMatrix * a_position;
}
```